# why this JsFile can't excute some shell, when systemctl service excution situation

Tags: node.js, shell, ubuntu, child-process, systemctl

when I excute this program directly,
all exec() shell is working,,,,

But,,,, MyStory vv

I registered my nodejs program in systemctl,

service name is speaker
and path is /etc/systemd/system/speaker.service
content is

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/speaker/speakerModule/start.sh
WorkingDirectory=/home/speaker/speakerModule
User=speaker

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And /home/speaker/speakerModule/start.sh
content is
`#!/bin/bash /home/speaker/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin/node speaker.js`

First, I set chmod 775 or +x for systemctl
And When i input "systemctl enable speaker" and "systemctl start speaker"
service is working..

but when I excute program throgh systemcl,
exec() is working about only /usr/local/bin/gpio shell
without any other shells

Below is my NodeJs Program vV

```
const os = require("os");
const io = require("socket.io-client");
const {exec} = require('child_process');
const osType = os.type();
const RELAY = 26;
const SERVER_END_POINT = "http://172.30.1.29:3000";
const PLAYER_CONTROL_ENDPOINT = SERVER_END_POINT + "/api/player";
const SPEAKER_CONTROL_SK_ENDPOINT = SERVER_END_POINT + "/speaker";

console.log(osType);

if (osType !== "Linux") {
  console.log(
    "해당프로그램은 라즈베리파이OS 및 우분투와 같은 리눅스 기반에서 작동될 수 있습니다"
  );
  return;
}


function setVolume(volume) {
  if (volume < 0 || volume > 100) return;
    if (volume === 0) {
        exec(`/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write ${RELAY} 0`);
  } else {
        exec(`/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write ${RELAY} 1`);
  }
  exec(`/usr/bin/amixer -D pulse sset Master ${volume}%`);
}

const socket = io(SPEAKER_CONTROL_SK_ENDPOINT, {
  transports: ["websocket"],
  autoConnect : false
});

let reconnectInterval = null;
socket.on("connect_error", (error) => {
if(!reconnectInterval) {
reconnectInterval = setInterval(() => {
socket.connect();
console.log("CONNECTING TO SERVER...");
}, 3000);
}
});

socket.on("connect", (data) => {
console.log("connected");
if(reconnectInterval) {
clearInterval(reconnectInterval)
}
});

socket.on("disconnect", () => {
socket.connect()
})

socket.on("volume", async (data) => {
  const volume = Number(data);
  console.log(volume);
  setVolume(volume);
});

setVolume(30);
socket.connect();
///usr/bin/firefox
exec(`/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode ${RELAY} out`);
exec(`/usr/bin/firefox ${PLAYER_CONTROL_ENDPOINT}`);
```

Do you know this situation??....

when I excute this program directly,
all exec() shell is working,,,,

but when ubuntu systemctl starts nodeJs Program,
NodeJs Program is working,

but some exec() is not working..